# How to Plot a Half pie chart in Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jqplot

I have two form arrays,

```
$expenditure = $_POST['expenditure'];
$revennue = $_POST['revenue'];
```

I have to use the values from these array and plot a Pie chart ,Like half of the pie chart will show the relation of expenditure and other half revenue

I tried using Jqplot something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = [
  <?php foreach($revenue as $key=> $val){ 
         $x = ($val/array_sum($revennue))*180;   
  ?>
    ['<?php echo "rev_".$key ?>', <?php echo $x ?>],
<?php }?>
 <?php foreach($expenditure as $key=> $val){ 
         $x = ($val/array_sum($expenditure))*180;   
  ?>
    ['<?php echo "exp_".$key ?>', <?php echo $x ?>],
<?php }?>
  ];
  var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('chart1', [data],
    {
      seriesDefaults: {
        // Make this a pie chart.
        renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
          // Put data labels on the pie slices.
          // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
          showDataLabels: true
          this.startAngle = 180
        }
      },
      legend: { show:false, location: 'e' }
    }
  );
});
```

But its showing me wrong pie chart ,

Can Any one let  me know how I can fix this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: always add the rendered html rather than server side code.

Comment: @CerlinBoss bro Okay I will do that , But can you help me how I can draw half pie chart I have been researching every where on internet but with no luck :(

Comment: create a fiddle and share with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an attempt to draw Half Pie Chart.
 I don't know if there's an easier way to do this.

With the help of some calculations and hacks, I managed to plot one.
A dummy-data , `startAngle` , `shadowDepth` , `dataLabels` , `seriesColors` , `backgroundColor` helped me achieve this.
Here's the JSFiddle link for the same : [jqPLot - Half Pie Chart](http://jsfiddle.net/anish_nair/96vog3h1/1/)

NOTE: When you hover over the chart, you can see the dummy-slice.
I think you can fix that with a little research.

Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: I finished this project already :), I used some other plugin it had option for half pie chart , But I am accepting your answer 

Thanks